# Roots of a specific parametrized polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots, nonlinear-system

Let $M\in \mathbb{N}$ and $c\in(0,1)$. I want to solve in $x$
\begin{align}
c(1-x)^M +Mx-1 = 0, \\
0 \leq x \leq 1.
\end{align}

Even if it is a root-finding problem of a polynomial of degree $M$, I suspect (and hope) than it may exist an explicit solution to this problem. I cannot ensure the existance nor uniqueness of the solution of the problem but I strongly think that we have both.

Any idea how to tackle the problem ?

Comment: Have you tried doing $M=1$ or $M=2$?

Comment: What about $M=5$ ? We can make good *approximations* but no more.